# How does site name change impact to seo?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a site, ranked 1st in my purpose keyword of google search result.
I have to change brand name or site name, but I will not change domain url.
Does this change impact to seo? Will my site's ranking go down?
I want to know about the impact.

Comment: I don't think that it is going to change smth.

Comment: yeah may be , Because your site is better known by the previous brand and this way can reduce your ctr%

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the domain name and also all the urls in your site influence your SEO performance. The more keywords you have in your domain name, urls, content will influence your page rank and increase your positioning within the search results.

Comment: The question wasn't about keywords.  It was about brand name.  They specifically said the were not changing the URLs.